# How do you find the version of glassfish?

Tags: glassfish

How do you determine which version of GlassFish server is running?

This command:

```
/var/glassfish/bin/asadmin version
```

...returned:

```
Version = Sun Java System Application Server 9.1_01
Command version executed successfully.
```

Which version of GlassFish is this?

Answer (score 17):

1. Go to the GlassFish installed directory using terminal.

   ```
   cd /opt/glassfish3.1.2.2/glassfish/bin
   ```
2. Type this command in terminal

   ```
   ./asadmin version
   ```

Comment: Thanks, Was able to verify the version using the above command. Got the output as below: Version = Eclipse GlassFish  6.2.1  (build master-b569-gad91414 2021-08-26T23:45:22+0000)
Command version executed successfully.

Answer (score 3):

From the [GlassFish wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlassFish), it appears that Sun Java System Application Server `9.1` corresponds to GlassFish `v2`.

[This blog entry](https://blogs.oracle.com/alexismp/entry/gf_2_ur1_blog) also mentions that your specific version (`9.1_01`) corresponds to GlassFish `v2ur1`.

Answer (score 2):

`Sun Java System Application Server 9.1_01`

This is GlassFish 2.

See also:

- [Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Administration Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1751/ghhox/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

C:\glassfish4\glassfish\config\branding\glassfish-version.properties

```
product_name=GlassFish Server Open Source Edition
brief_product_name=GlassFish Server
abbrev_product_name=glassfish
major_version=4
minor_version=1
update_version=
build_id=13
version_prefix=
version_suffix=
default_domain_template=appserver-domain.jar
admin_client_command_name=asadmin
```